# Повторное использование PreparedStatement

Tags: java

Мне говорят, что я не правильно использую PS: *"нужно один раз инициализировать, много раз его использовать и потом один раз закрыть"*.

```
public class MarkDao extends Dao<Mark> {

    Connection connection = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    PreparedStatement insert = null;
    PreparedStatement select = null;
    PreparedStatement delete = null;
    PreparedStatement update = null;

    private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student";
    private String password = "root";
    private String user = "root";

    public Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            if (connection == null) {
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, password, user);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }

    @Override
    public void insert(Mark obj) {
        String sql = "insert into mark ( student_id, discipline_id, mark) values (?,?,?);";
        try {
            insert = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            insert.setInt(1, obj.getStudent_id());
            insert.setInt(2, obj.getDiscipline_id());
            insert.setInt(3, obj.getMark());
            insert.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            closePreparedStatement();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List <Mark> select() {
        List <Mark> marks = new LinkedList<>();
        String sql = "select id, student_id, discipline_id, mark from mark";
        Mark mark = null;
        try {
            select = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            resultSet = select.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                mark = new Mark();
                mark.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                mark.setStudent_id(resultSet.getInt("student_id"));
                mark.setDiscipline_id(resultSet.getInt("discipline_id"));
                mark.setMark(resultSet.getInt("mark"));
                marks.add(mark);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (resultSet != null) {
                try {
                    resultSet.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        closePreparedStatement();
        System.out.println(marks);
        return marks;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Mark obj, int id) {
        String sql = "delete from mark where id=?;";
        try {
            delete = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            delete.setInt(1, id);
            delete.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        closePreparedStatement();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Mark obj) {
        String sql = "Update mark set mark=? where id=?;";
        try {
            update = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            update.setInt(1, obj.getId());
            update.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        closePreparedStatement();
    }

    public void closeConnection() {
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { }
    }

    public void closePreparedStatement() {
        try {
            if (insert != null) {
                insert.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (select != null) {
                select.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (update != null) {
                update.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (delete != null) {
                delete.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

То есть, допустим, здесь сколько раз будет вызываться `insert` - столько будет вызываться создание PS.

А нужно один раз создать перед всеми вызовами, и один раз закрыть после всех вызовов.

```
public void insert(Mark obj) {
    String sql = "insert into mark ( student_id, discipline_id, mark) values (?,?,?);";
    try {
        insert = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        insert.setInt(1, obj.getStudent_id());
        insert.setInt(2, obj.getDiscipline_id());
        insert.setInt(3, obj.getMark());
        insert.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        closePreparedStatement();
    }
}
```

Непонятно что нужно делать. Я посмотрел много примеров использования PS, но  то, что от меня требуется (*"Один раз открыть, много раз использовать, один раз закрыть"*), не встречал.

Comment: В чем собственно вопрос?

Comment: Не понятно ,что нужно делать.Я уже столько примеров использования PS посмотрел . Но то,что от меня требуется "Один раз открыть,много раз использовать , один раз закрыть" не встречал.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы обратили внимание, то создание экземпляра `PreparedStatement` происходит с помощью объекта класса `Connection`. В вашем конкретном случае очевидным решением является перенос логики закрытия `PreparedStatement` в метод `closeConnection` непосредственно перед закрытием соединения.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String INSERT_MARK = "INSERT INTO mark (student_ID, subject_ID, mark) VALUES (?, ?, ?);";   

private Connection connection;
private PreparedStatement statement;
private ResultSet rs;

public MarkDao() throws DaoException {
    Properties prop = new Properties();             
    try {
        prop.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("db.properties"));                       
        String url = prop.getProperty("url");
        String name = prop.getProperty("name");
        String pass = prop.getProperty("pass");
        String driver = prop.getProperty("driver");                 
        Class.forName(driver);          
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, name, pass);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DaoException(e);
        }                       
}
protected void prepareStatementForInsert(PreparedStatement statement, Mark mark) throws DaoException {
    try {
        statement.setInt(1, mark.getStudent_ID());
        statement.setInt(2, mark.getSubject_ID());
        statement.setInt(3, mark.getMark());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DaoException(e);
        }
}
public void insert(Mark mark) throws DaoException {
    String sql = INSERT_MARK;
    try {
         statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql); 
         prepareStatementForInsert(statement, mark); 
         statement.executeUpdate();                 
    } catch (Exception e) {             
        throw new DaoException(e);
        }
}
public void close() throws DaoException{
    try {       
        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();             
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();            
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DaoException(e);
      }
}
```

}

Код рабочий, но не идеален, полагаю ваш ментор имеет ввиду это.
Может кто-нибудь знает как сделать этот код лучше???